# Problem with resetting origin of mesh and 3D landmarks in R - origin set far away from mesh centre

Tags: r, mesh, rgl

I have recently started having problems with how my meshes are read into r. It seems to be a problem with the origin of each mesh being set to some distance away from the actual mesh itself. This makes them almost impossible to view and manipulate in an rgl window (see image below).
eshes are .ply files created using a surface scanner and decimated in MeshLab. This problem has only started occurring since I updated to R version 4.2.1 and geomorph 4.0.4. Prior to this the same meshes worked fine!

```
uncentred <- read.ply("uncentred.ply")
rgl.bbox()
```

[image: an uncentred mesh showing the distance between mesh & origin. Note origin is located at base of bounding box.]

I can reset the mesh origin in an external program (e.g. MeshLab - 'Filters' - 'Transform: translate, centre, set origin' -  'Centre on Scene BBox') and reimport it into R which solves the issue of viewing the mesh in an rgl window:

```
centred <- read.ply("centred.ply")
rgl.bbox()
```

[image: centred mesh with origin recentred in MeshLab]

BUT as I have already landmarked all of my meshes (in Stratovan Checkpoint) this would result in all of my landmark coordinates being located at the original origin and far away from their associated meshes (see example below). This is problematic for doing subsequent visualisations for geometric morphometric analyses:

```
plot3d(Data.train[,,1], aspect =  FALSE, size =10, col="green")
shade3d(centred)
```

[image: centred mesh showing different locations of 3D landmark coordinates and newly centred mesh]

Is there a way I can reset the origin of my meshes AND their associated 3D landmark coordinates in r without having to re-landmark my whole dataset?

Comment: I'm looking at your last plot/graph and asking myself, why does it look like [gpagen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74348805/why-does-the-general-procrustes-analysis-result-doesnt-has-the-same-shape-of-or). The tendency is to think 'I've done something wrong...' Or not. Perhaps something came up in 4.0.4. Perhaps your and `gpagen` should talk, or perhaps over at github geomorph. It is curious.

Comment: Could you make a problematic `.ply` file available somewhere, and include all the packages you used?  `read.ply` isn't an `rgl` function.  I'd guess it is including some data at the origin, and removing that will fix the problem, but it's hard to tell you how to do that without reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted any data that we can use, so I'll use simple fake data:  a tetrahedron centered at (50, 0, 0), with an additional point at the origin:

```r
library(rgl)

tetra <- translate3d(tetrahedron3d(col = "red"), 50, 0, 0)
plot3d(tetra)
points3d(0,0,0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

To make the tetrahedron more visible, we can limit the view to just values with `x > 49`:

```r
library(rgl)

tetra <- translate3d(tetrahedron3d(col = "red"), 50, 0, 0)
plot3d(tetra)
points3d(0,0,0)
clipplanes3d(1, 0, 0, -49)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This messes up the axes a little, but might be enough for what you need.